# Renaming all files inside a folder using a .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-io, cmd

I want to rename all the files inside a folder using a `.bat`.
But I experience a problem, instead of renaming the file it concatenates the name.

Example:

Old name before running the `.bat`:                          **test.txt**

New name after running the `.bat`: **test newname.txt**

This is the code:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt') do ren "%%~i" "%%~ni newname%%~xi"
```

I am using Windows 8 but I don’t know if that is relevant.

Comment: it's doing this, because you tell it to do. `%%~ni` is the (old) name of the file without extension. Check the second parameter in the `ren`command.

Comment: Have a look here; http://superuser.com/questions/728312/renaming-multiple-files-inside-a-folder-using-windows-batch-commands

Comment: If you have 3 files a.txt, b.txt and c.txt, should all 3 of them be renamed to newname.txt - how will that work - you cannot have three files in a folder with the same name

Comment: The code is doing its job, although error-prone. What do you want to rename it to?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem occurs because you've told `ren` to do **exactly** what it's done.

```
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt') do ren 
                                        "%%~i" from this name
                                                "%%~ni newname%%~xi" to this name
```

The new name is

```
"%%~ni the name part of the original filename
      Space A space
                newname the text "newname"
                       %%~xi" the extension part of the original filename
```

Since you haven't told us what you want this file renamed **to**, we can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help.

The error was mine I was trying to rename to a name to later use a random to create new name.

The problem was I didn’t consider that I all the files in the folder cannot have the same name